# iText methods of 7.1.3 in Android

Tags: java, android, itext

I cannot use the getInstance() method of the PdfWriter class nor can I use the open() method of the document...how do I fix?

I have `iText package 7.1.3`.

My code is as below:

```
PdfWriter.class.getConstructor(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));

document.open();
```

I am converting an image to pdf btw

Comment: have you provided necessary permission in your manifest?

Comment: iText 7 doesn't have those methods anymore. Best read the iText 7 tutorials instead of trying to copy-paste your iText 5 code to iText 7. That last bit will not work, because the API is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the basic demonstration of code picked from tutorialspoint, hope this will helps you.

```
// Creating a PdfWriter 
String dest = "C:/hellodearcode/imgtest.pdf"; 
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
// Creating a PdfDocument  
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer); 
// Creating a Document OBJECT
document = new Document(pdfDoc); 
// Creating an ImageData object 
String imageFile = "C:/hellodearcode/tabishrana-blog.jpg"; 
ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.create(imageFile);
// Creating an Image object 
Image img = new Image(data); 
// close document
document.close();
```

you should follow this object creation flow to make a successful call

```
import com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageData; 
import com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory; 

import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument; 
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;

import com.itextpdf.layout.Document; 
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Image;  

public class AddingImage {      
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {              

      // Creating a PdfWriter       
      String dest = "C:/itextExamples/addingImage.pdf";       
      PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);        

      // Creating a PdfDocument       
      PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);              

      // Creating a Document        
      Document document = new Document(pdf);              

      // Creating an ImageData object       
      String imFile = "C:/itextExamples/logo.jpg";       
      ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.create(imFile);              

      // Creating an Image object        
      Image image = new Image(data);                        

      // Adding image to the document       
      document.add(image);              

      // Closing the document       
      document.close();              

      System.out.println("Image added");    
   } 
}
```